# Cannot read an Excel 97-2004 Workbook

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have been struggling so much to read a Excel file which I scraped from a web page. It has the type: Microsoft Excel 97-2004 Workbook (I checked it from MS Excel). This is what I am trying with PHPExcel:

```
$destination = APPPATH . "docs/app.xls";
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($destination);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($destination);
```

and I get the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: simplexml_load_file(): /var/www/application/cookies/app.xls:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Filename: Reader/Excel2003XML.php

Line Number: 333

....
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: simplexml_load_file(): HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Filename: Reader/Excel2003XML.php

Line Number: 333
...

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: simplexml_load_file(): ^

Filename: Reader/Excel2003XML.php

Line Number: 333
...

Fatal error: Call to a member function getNamespaces() on boolean in /var/www/application/third_party/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2003XML.php on line 334
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function getNamespaces() on boolean
```

Can anyone help me to sort it out?

Comment: Looks as though PHPExcel is recognising it as SpreadsheetML format, but perhaps it's not cleanly formed..... but as I can't see the file in question, I can't tell for certain

Comment: @SeanBright PHPExcel works with .xls right?

Comment: @MarkBaker can I upload the file in some where and share?

Comment: PHPExcel works with most spreadsheet formats, and even handles a lot of malformed files, but there's limits to how much I can program around files that don't follow the standards

Comment: @MarkBaker I thought that as well, but I can't help it. the remote server has some bad software practice. and I am helpless. :/

Comment: @MarkBaker I have sent an email .please check.

Comment: @MarkBaker looks like the file is in BIFF format. As per the doc PHPExcel supports BIFF files right?

Comment: No it isn't BIFF Format, it's a corrupted SpreadsheetML format file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your file is that it isn't simply the SpreadsheetML format, it's corrupted.

Opening the file in a text editor, I can see that the http response headers are also included in the file

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 13 Nov 2015 09:55:31 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="sdp_daily_app_revenue_report.xls"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>

<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
....
</Workbook>
```

This makes it unreadable..... the file should contain nothing but the actual xml content

I don't know how you're acquiring it, but you need to ensure that the http response headers aren't echoed out into the file. PHPExcel should read it without issue if everything before the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` was stripped out

**EDIT**

It's also defined without a `Default` style, which is mandatory for SpreadsheetML format.... if you want to hack the code of the Excel2003XML Reader a bit around lines 413-417, change

```
if ($styleID == 'Default') {
    $this->styles['Default'] = array();
} else {
    $this->styles[$styleID] = $this->styles['Default'];
}
```

to

```
$this->styles[$styleID] = (isset($this->styles['Default'])) ? $this->styles['Default'] : array();
```

Comment: Thanks Mark,Looks like I have written the response header to the file.  I tried it with the file you gave, It still gives me an error. Message: Undefined index: Default

Filename: Reader/Excel2003XML.php

Line Number: 416